# Windows API gui designer?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gui-designer

Is there a good GUI designer (read: drag 'n drop/WYSIWYG) for the plain old Windows API? I'm not looking for something that uses Qt, GTK, .NET, etc, just plain old Windows API.

Must be usable with either C or C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for a resource editor. Visual Studio Professional, Premium and Ultimate have one built into the IDE. You can access it by creating a new .rc file and then adding a resource to it.

If you're not using Visual Studio you can use an external resource editor such as ResEdit. Not having it built into the IDE is a little bit more of a hassle unfortunately.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a pertinent answer. You might add that a resource editor only allows you to edit *dialogs*, not arbitrary windows.

Comment: The downvoter might be on crusade against the world. From behind his computer screen that is.

Comment: I just wanted to add that ResEdit can also generate code that will create your designed dialogs as windows; i.e. with CreateWindow[Ex]. The caveat is that as is often with generated code, it is **very** messy.

Comment: How can I add resources to *.rc file?